# UITextView not scrollable when on image attachment

Tags: ios, uitextview, attachment

I have `UITextView` with `attributedString` and image attachment. The `UITextView` is **not editable** but *selectable*.

The problem is with image attachment. When I start to scroll the `UITextView`, and the touch(my finger) started on an image attachment. It's not scrollable at most times. If I scroll very quickly, it would work. But if I hold my finger at image attachment even with very little duration, It would not scroll.
The touch is recognized as selection on image attachment (image would highlight after I remove my finger).

I tried to disable `UITextView`'s `isSelectable` property, the problem goes away. But that is not what I want. I want it to be selectable on the ordinary text.

I tried to disable all `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` of `UITextView` with no luck. The problem is still there.

Can I have a solution where I can remain selectable, and avoid image attachment eats up the scroll in the meantime? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done.

I suppose in `UITextView`, the implementation of selection is through `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, and the implementation of scrolling is through `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.
So, if I prevent long-press gesture from being recognized until the pan gesture fails, the long-press would not eat up scroll anymore.

First, I have `UITextView` subclass. In that subclass, loop through `UIGestureRecognizers` to `UITextView` at the appropriate point. I did it in method `didMoveToSuperview()`.

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    if let grs = gestureRecognizers {
        for gr in grs {
            if gr.isKind(of: UIPanGestureRecognizer.self) {
                // set delegate
                gr.delegate = self
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second, implement method `gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool` from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.

```
extension CustomTextView: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {    
    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldBeRequiredToFailBy otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        // all UILongPressGestureRecognizer has to wait UIPanGestureRecognizer to be failed before recognized
        if gestureRecognizer.isKind(of: UIPanGestureRecognizer.self) && otherGestureRecognizer.isKind(of: UILongPressGestureRecognizer.self) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

[Reference from apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another)